# Getting error while creating a scheduled job in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a scheduled job in SharePoint. 
I get the following error while calling update() function.

> when deploying an office solution, check to make sure you have fulfilled all necessary security requirements

I am using SQL Server 2008 and SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly provide full trust in the security policy for your scheduled job code assembly [level of trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exya3kf%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, just giving full trust may not be an option. You need to carefully evaluate what permissions you need to grant to your code and according create a Code Access Security policy for your solution package.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bats0y2a(VS.80).aspx